# how to navigate from one page to the other in j2me

Tags: list, java-me, uinavigationcontroller

I am newbie to J2ME. I am trying to navigate from one MIDlet page to the other on the selection of ListItem. But I am getting following error message.

```
Installing suite from: file:///C:/Users/mohit/Documents/NetBeansProjects/MobileApp1/dist/nbrun8756732879038612272/MobileApp1.jad
6370272 - ERROR - AMS - 2 - Installation failed:com.sun.midp.midletsuite.MIDletSuiteLockedException
com.sun.midp.midletsuite.MIDletSuiteLockedException
at com.sun.midp.midletsuite.MIDletSuiteImpl.lockMIDletSuite(), bci=0
at com.sun.midp.midletsuite.MIDletSuiteStorage.getMIDletSuite(), bci=12
at com.sun.midp.installer.Installer.checkPreviousVersion(), bci=60
at com.sun.midp.installer.Installer.installStep2(), bci=10
at com.sun.midp.installer.Installer.performInstall(), bci=132
at com.sun.midp.installer.Installer.resumeInstallation(), bci=7
at com.sun.midp.installer.MidpInstaller$StartAction.run(), bci=10
at com.sun.j2me.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(), bci=12
at com.sun.midp.installer.MidpInstaller$InstallThread.run(), bci=9
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:721)

TRACE: <at java.lang.NullPointerException:   0>, Exception caught in Display class
java.lang.NullPointerException:   0
 - mobileapp1.VisualMIDlet.commandAction(VisualMIDlet.java:180)
at javax.microedition.lcdui.Display$ChameleonTunnel.callScreenListener(), bci=39
at com.sun.midp.chameleon.layers.SoftButtonLayer.processCommand(), bci=62
at com.sun.midp.chameleon.layers.SoftButtonLayer.soft2(), bci=119
at com.sun.midp.chameleon.layers.SoftButtonLayer.keyInput(), bci=102
at com.sun.midp.chameleon.CWindow.keyInput(), bci=30
at javax.microedition.lcdui.Display$DisplayEventConsumerImpl.handleKeyEvent(), bci=43
at com.sun.midp.lcdui.DisplayEventListener.process(), bci=252
at com.sun.midp.events.EventQueue.run(), bci=130
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:721)
```

I don't know how to handle this one. Can anyone help me out,please?

```
//VisualMIDlet.java
package mobileapp1;

import javax.microedition.midlet.*;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.*;
import org.netbeans.microedition.lcdui.LoginScreen;

public class VisualMIDlet extends MIDlet implements CommandListener {

private boolean midletPaused = false;

private java.util.Hashtable __previousDisplayables = new java.util.Hashtable();
private LoginScreen loginScreen;
private Form FallSem_Home;
private ChoiceGroup choiceGroup;
private List stud_homelist;
private Form WinterSem_Home;
private Command exit_StudList;
private Command exitCommand1;
private Command exitCommand2;
private Command backCommand;
private Command ok_StudList;
private Command okCommand;

private List menu = null;
private Display display;
Fall_Sem fall_sem;
public VisualMIDlet() {
    //fall_sem = new Fall_Sem();
}


private void switchToPreviousDisplayable() {
    Displayable __currentDisplayable = getDisplay().getCurrent();
    if (__currentDisplayable != null) {
        Displayable __nextDisplayable = (Displayable) __previousDisplayables.get(__currentDisplayable);
        if (__nextDisplayable != null) {
            switchDisplayable(null, __nextDisplayable);
        }
    }
}

private void initialize() {
    // write pre-initialize user code here

    // write post-initialize user code here
}

public void startMIDlet() {
    // write pre-action user code here
    switchDisplayable(null, getLoginScreen());
    // write post-action user code here
}

public void resumeMIDlet() {
    // write pre-action user code here

    // write post-action user code here
}

public void switchDisplayable(Alert alert, Displayable nextDisplayable) {
    // write pre-switch user code here
    Display display = getDisplay();
    Displayable __currentDisplayable = display.getCurrent();
    if (__currentDisplayable != null && nextDisplayable != null) {
        __previousDisplayables.put(nextDisplayable, __currentDisplayable);
    }
    if (alert == null) {
        display.setCurrent(nextDisplayable);
    } else {
        display.setCurrent(alert, nextDisplayable);
    }
    // write post-switch user code here
}

public void commandAction(Command command, Displayable displayable) {
    // write pre-action user code here
    if (displayable == FallSem_Home) {
        if (command == backCommand) {
            // write pre-action user code here

            // write post-action user code here
        } else if (command == exit_StudList) {
            // write pre-action user code here
            //notifyDestroyed();

            // write post-action user code here
        } else if (command == okCommand) {
            // write pre-action user code here


            // write post-action user code here
        }
    } else if (displayable == WinterSem_Home) {
        if (command == backCommand) {
            // write pre-action user code here
            switchToPreviousDisplayable();
            // write post-action user code here
        } else if (command == exitCommand2) {
            // write pre-action user code here

            // write post-action user code here
        }
    } else if (displayable == loginScreen) {
        if (command == LoginScreen.LOGIN_COMMAND) {
            // write pre-action user code here
            if(loginScreen.getUsername().equals("mohit") && loginScreen.getPassword().equals("abhi")){
                switchDisplayable(null, getStud_homelist());
            // write post-action user code here
            }
        }
    } else if (displayable == stud_homelist) {
        if (command == List.SELECT_COMMAND) {
            // write pre-action user code here
            stud_homelistAction();
            // write post-action user code here
        } else if (command == exit_StudList) {
            // write pre-action user code here
            exitMIDlet();
            // write post-action user code here
        } **else if (command == ok_StudList) {
            // write pre-action user code here
            List options = (List) display.getCurrent();
            switch(options.getSelectedIndex()){
                case 0:

                    displayable = fall_sem.getForm();
                    switchDisplayable(null, displayable);
                    //display.setCurrent(fall_sem.getForm());
            }

            // write post-action user code here
        }**
    }
    // write post-action user code here
}

public LoginScreen getLoginScreen() {
    if (loginScreen == null) {
        // write pre-init user code here
        loginScreen = new LoginScreen(getDisplay());
        loginScreen.setLabelTexts("Username", "Password");
        loginScreen.setTitle("loginScreen");
        loginScreen.addCommand(LoginScreen.LOGIN_COMMAND);
        loginScreen.setCommandListener(this);
        loginScreen.setFullScreenMode(true);
        loginScreen.setBGColor(-3355444);
        loginScreen.setFGColor(0);
        loginScreen.setPassword("");
        loginScreen.setUsername("");
        loginScreen.setUseLoginButton(true);
        loginScreen.setLoginButtonText("Login");
        // write post-init user code here
    }
    return loginScreen;
}

public Form getFallSem_Home() {
    if (FallSem_Home == null) {
        // write pre-init user code here
        FallSem_Home = new Form("form", new Item[]{getChoiceGroup()});
        FallSem_Home.addCommand(getExit_StudList());
        FallSem_Home.addCommand(getBackCommand());
        FallSem_Home.addCommand(getOkCommand());
        FallSem_Home.setCommandListener(this);
        // write post-init user code here
    }
    return FallSem_Home;
}

public Command getExit_StudList() {
    if (exit_StudList == null) {
        // write pre-init user code here
        exit_StudList = new Command("Exit", Command.EXIT, 0);
        // write post-init user code here
    }
    return exit_StudList;
}

public ChoiceGroup getChoiceGroup() {
    if (choiceGroup == null) {
        // write pre-init user code here
        choiceGroup = new ChoiceGroup("choices", Choice.EXCLUSIVE);
        choiceGroup.append("Time Table", null);
        choiceGroup.append("Exam Schedule", null);
        choiceGroup.append("Marks", null);
        choiceGroup.setFitPolicy(Choice.TEXT_WRAP_DEFAULT);
        choiceGroup.setSelectedFlags(new boolean[]{false, false, false});
        // write post-init user code here
    }
    return choiceGroup;
}

public List getStud_homelist() {
    if (stud_homelist == null) {
        // write pre-init user code here
        stud_homelist = new List("list", Choice.IMPLICIT);
        stud_homelist.append("Fall Sem 2012-13", null);
        stud_homelist.append("Winter Sem 2012-13", null);
        stud_homelist.append("Add / Drop", null);
        stud_homelist.addCommand(getExit_StudList());
        stud_homelist.addCommand(getOk_StudList());
        stud_homelist.setCommandListener(this);
        stud_homelist.setSelectedFlags(new boolean[]{false, false, false});
        // write post-init user code here
    }
    return stud_homelist;
}

public void stud_homelistAction() {
    // enter pre-action user code here
    String __selectedString = getStud_homelist().getString(getStud_homelist().getSelectedIndex());
    if (__selectedString != null) {
        if (__selectedString.equals("Fall Sem 2012-13")) {
            // write pre-action user code here

            // write post-action user code here
        } else if (__selectedString.equals("Winter Sem 2012-13")) {
            // write pre-action user code here

            // write post-action user code here
        } else if (__selectedString.equals("Add / Drop")) {
            // write pre-action user code here

            // write post-action user code here
        }
    }
    // enter post-action user code here
}

public Form getWinterSem_Home() {
    if (WinterSem_Home == null) {
        // write pre-init user code here
        WinterSem_Home = new Form("form");
        WinterSem_Home.addCommand(getBackCommand());
        WinterSem_Home.addCommand(getExitCommand2());
        WinterSem_Home.setCommandListener(this);
        // write post-init user code here
    }
    return WinterSem_Home;
}

public Command getExitCommand1() {
    if (exitCommand1 == null) {
        // write pre-init user code here
        exitCommand1 = new Command("Exit", Command.EXIT, 0);
        // write post-init user code here
    }
    return exitCommand1;
}

public Command getBackCommand() {
    if (backCommand == null) {
        // write pre-init user code here
        backCommand = new Command("Back", Command.BACK, 0);
        // write post-init user code here
    }
    return backCommand;
}

public Command getExitCommand2() {
    if (exitCommand2 == null) {
        // write pre-init user code here
        exitCommand2 = new Command("Exit", Command.EXIT, 0);
        // write post-init user code here
    }
    return exitCommand2;
}


public Command getOkCommand() {
    if (okCommand == null) {
        // write pre-init user code here
        okCommand = new Command("Ok", Command.OK, 0);
        // write post-init user code here
    }
    return okCommand;
}

public Command getOk_StudList() {
    if (ok_StudList == null) {
        // write pre-init user code here
        ok_StudList = new Command("Ok", Command.OK, 0);
        // write post-init user code here
    }
    return ok_StudList;
}

public Display getDisplay() {
    return Display.getDisplay(this);
}

public void exitMIDlet() {
    switchDisplayable(null, null);
    destroyApp(true);
    notifyDestroyed();
}

public void startApp() {
    if (midletPaused) {
        resumeMIDlet();
    } else {
        initialize();
        startMIDlet();
    }
    midletPaused = false;
}

public void pauseApp() {
    midletPaused = true;
}

public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {
            notifyDestroyed();

}
}



 //Fall_Sem.java
package mobileapp1;

import javax.microedition.midlet.*;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.*;
import org.netbeans.microedition.lcdui.LoginScreen;
import org.netbeans.microedition.lcdui.SimpleTableModel;
import org.netbeans.microedition.lcdui.TableItem;

public class Fall_Sem extends MIDlet implements CommandListener {

private boolean midletPaused = false;
private Display display;

private Form form;
private ChoiceGroup choiceGroup;
private Form form1;
private TableItem tableItem;
private Command backCommand;
private Command okCommand;
private Command exitCommand;
private Command exitCommand1;
private Command backCommand1;
private SimpleTableModel simpleTableModel;
public Fall_Sem() {
    System.out.println("Fall Sem");
}

private void initialize() {                                         
    // write pre-initialize user code here

    // write post-initialize user code here
}                            
public void startMIDlet() {                                      
    // write pre-action user code here
    switchDisplayable(null, getForm());                                        
    // write post-action user code here
}                             
public void resumeMIDlet() {                                       
    // write pre-action user code here

    // write post-action user code here
}                              
public void switchDisplayable(Alert alert, Displayable nextDisplayable) {                                            
    // write pre-switch user code here
    Display display = getDisplay();                                               
    if (alert == null) {
        display.setCurrent(nextDisplayable);
    } else {
        display.setCurrent(alert, nextDisplayable);
    }                                             
    // write post-switch user code here
}                                   
public Form getForm() {
    if (form == null) {                                 
        // write pre-init user code here
        form = new Form("form", new Item[] getChoiceGroup()});                                    
        form.addCommand(getBackCommand());
        form.addCommand(getOkCommand());
        form.addCommand(getExitCommand());
        form.setCommandListener(this);                                  
        // write post-init user code here
    }                         
    return form;
}
public ChoiceGroup getChoiceGroup() {
    if (choiceGroup == null) {                                 
        // write pre-init user code here
        choiceGroup = new ChoiceGroup("Choices", Choice.EXCLUSIVE);                                    
        choiceGroup.append("Time Table", null);
        choiceGroup.append("Exam Schedule", null);
        choiceGroup.append("Marks", null);
        choiceGroup.setSelectedFlags(new boolean[]{false, false, false});                                  
        // write post-init user code here
    }                         
    return choiceGroup;
}
public void commandAction(Command command, Displayable displayable) {                                               
    // write pre-action user code here
    if (displayable == form) {                                           
        if (command == backCommand) {                                         
            // write pre-action user code here

            // write post-action user code here
        } else if (command == exitCommand) {                                          
            // write pre-action user code here
            exitMIDlet();                                           
            // write post-action user code here
        } else if (command == okCommand) {                                          
            // write pre-action user code here
            switchDisplayable(null, getForm1());                                           
            // write post-action user code here
        }                                           
    } else if (displayable == form1) {
        if (command == backCommand1) {                                         
            // write pre-action user code here

            // write post-action user code here
        } else if (command == exitCommand1) {                                          
            // write pre-action user code here
            exitMIDlet();                                            
            // write post-action user code here
        }                                                   
    }                                                 
    // write post-action user code here
}                                             
public Form getForm1() {
    if (form1 == null) {                                 
        // write pre-init user code here
        form1 = new Form("form1", new Item[]{getTableItem()});                                    
        form1.addCommand(getBackCommand1());
        form1.addCommand(getExitCommand1());
        form1.setCommandListener(this);                                  
        // write post-init user code here
    }                         
    return form1;
}
public TableItem getTableItem() {
    if (tableItem == null) {                                 
        // write pre-init user code here
        tableItem = new TableItem(getDisplay(), "tableItem");                                   
        // write post-init user code here

    }                         
    return tableItem;
}
public Command getBackCommand() {
    if (backCommand == null) {                                 
        // write pre-init user code here
        backCommand = new Command("Back", Command.BACK, 0);                                   
        // write post-init user code here
    }                         
    return backCommand;
}
public Command getOkCommand() {
    if (okCommand == null) {                                 
        // write pre-init user code here
        okCommand = new Command("Ok", Command.OK, 0);                                   
        // write post-init user code here
    }                         
    return okCommand;
}
public Command getExitCommand() {
    if (exitCommand == null) {                                 
        // write pre-init user code here
        exitCommand = new Command("Exit", Command.EXIT, 0);                                   
        // write post-init user code here
    }                         
    return exitCommand;
}
public Command getBackCommand1() {
    if (backCommand1 == null) {                                 
        // write pre-init user code here
        backCommand1 = new Command("Back", Command.BACK, 0);                                   
        // write post-init user code here
    }                         
    return backCommand1;
}
public Command getExitCommand1() {
    if (exitCommand1 == null) {                                 
        // write pre-init user code here
        exitCommand1 = new Command("Exit", Command.EXIT, 0);                                   
        // write post-init user code here
    }                         
    return exitCommand1;
}
public SimpleTableModel getSimpleTableModel() {
    if (simpleTableModel == null) {                                 
        // write pre-init user code here
        simpleTableModel = new SimpleTableModel(null, null);                                   
        // write post-init user code here
    }                         
    return simpleTableModel;
}
public Display getDisplay() {
    return Display.getDisplay(this);
}

public void exitMIDlet() {
    switchDisplayable(null, null);
    destroyApp(true);
    notifyDestroyed();
}

public void startApp() {
    if (midletPaused) {
        resumeMIDlet();
    } else {
        initialize();
        startMIDlet();
    }
    midletPaused = false;
}

public void pauseApp() {
    midletPaused = true;
}

public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {
}
}
```

Comment: The code you put in has some extra asterisks around the last else if branch in commandAction. The NullPointerException from your TRACE points at commandAction in line 180, but in the code this method is from line 76 to 136. Can you provide the actual code that caused the error?

Comment: @Gregor Ophey: it is the same code. I have intentionally put the asterisks here in this que.  On selection of 'stud_homelist'value, when I click on command button 'ok_StudList', new form should open which is in another MIDlet file. I think, error is in that part only. please tell me, how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote an example on how to do list selection based navigation in my other answer here: 
[Get event click list item in J2ME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14612842/get-event-click-list-item-in-j2me/14682463#14682463)

Comment: thanks.. i got the result by that way. But my question is about whether can we keep 2 classes extended from MIDlet in the same project? If yes, then how can we call a form in second class from the first class?

Comment: Ok, that's a different question. Quick answer is, that you should not have two MIDlets in the same J2ME app (I'm not sure if you can't). But you can have separate classes e.g. for your Screens (Forms and Lists and such). You could do something MVC-like by keeping the controller in your MIDlet, have the views in your screen classes, both working with your model implemented in plain JAVA. That's what I would recommend, whenever you have to customize a screen derived class, or when putting everyting in the MIDlet gets out of hand (> 500 lines) ...